# Optimization setting

Tags: c, compiler-flags

In c we can enble the optimization setting by enabling the flag -O for enable all the possible optimization and -O0 will disable all enabled optimization.

My question is that this flags are message to whom?means to compiler or kernel?

Comment: Look at your compiler options. Generally it is `-O` (capital `O`) then optimization level `0-3` (or `fast` for gcc >= 4.6). (e.g. `-O3`) They describe how aggressive the *compiler* should be in producing the executable code.

Comment: [Some gcc docs.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)

Comment: Frequently used variables can be stored as **register**, this can reduce loop execution times by 50%.

Comment: @arif burhan ..useful information...thanks

Comment: @david c. Rankin ..thanks for correction .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All command line arguments you supply are interpreted by the compiler (or compiler driver, in the case of some compilers like gcc).    They may then be passed on to other programs that the compiler (or compiler driver) executes to complete particular tasks.

Incidentally, `-o` is not an optimisation setting with quite a few compilers.  It usually specifies the name of an output file.   For example, `gcc -c file.c -o anotherfile.o`  compilers `file.c` and produces an object file named `anotherfile.o`.

The optimisation setting is usually `-O`  (for example `-O3`).   Note the uppercase `O`.      It won't necessarily be passed to every program executed by the compiler/driver.  For example, `gcc -O3 file.c -o program` compiles `file.c` with optimisation setting `-O3` and produces an output executable named `program`.   To do that, the linker is invoked, as well as various compilation phases (preprocessor, compiler proper, etc).   `-O3` will not normally be passed to the linker - it is a compilation option which linkers normally do not understand.

Answer (score -1):

The `O` flags are passed to the compiler, not the kernel. The kernel has nothing to do with compilation. These flags determine how aggressively the optimizer will do it's job. A practical example would be `clang -O3 WannabeObjectFile.c`.

*Edit:* I made a mistake, the lower case `o` flag is used to specify the output file. The uppercase `O` is used to specify optimization level.